# ECS TASK alerts on OutOfMemory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

If a ECS container is out of memory or is in hung state or stopped thought is gets restarted. is there a way to I se up alarms on top of that using cloudwatch or directly from the task logs? because the OutOfMemory error that I saw in Task logs was not in cloudwatch logs and later the stopped task got removed.

error I see in stopped task `STOPPED (OutOfMemoryError: Container killed due to memory u)`

Comment: Limit your task's memory, that's the first thing you should do. Because right now it looks like your task consumes most of the host machine’s memory. On Linux hosts, when the kernel detects that there isn't enough memory to perform important system functions, it throws an **OutOfMemory exception**.

Comment: After we limit it , still the ECS will crash when we reach the limit. right
How can we set an alert on ECS so that we get an alert on crash

Comment: I'd test the app thoroughly locally, first, as that memory consumption is something to do at an app level.

Answer (score 0):

Create an AWS EventBridge Rule which will trigger when there is a State Change in AWS ECS due to OOM.
Use the below JSON to create an AWS Event

```json
{
  "detail-type": ["ECS Task State Change"],
  "source": ["aws.ecs"],
  "detail": {
    "clusterArn": ["arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:xxxxx:cluster/xxxxxxxx"],
    "stoppedReason": ["OutOfMemoryError: container killed due to memory usage"],
    "lastStatus": ["STOPPED"]
  }
}
```

To add some points

- Adding Cluster and Service Details is Optional
- stoppedReason must match the error thrown by your container.
- The above rule can be a bit noisy if your container is restarting continuously and you integrate it with your SRE Team. You can monitor the Event Rule in CloudWatch and Create an Alarm there. Use CloudWatch Alarm configurations to reduce some noise.

Alternatively, You can use the exit code to trigger the AWS EventBridge Rule

```json
{
  "detail-type": [
    "ECS Task State Change"
  ],
  "source": [
    "aws.ecs"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "lastStatus": [
      "STOPPED"
    ],
    "containers": {
      "exitCode": [
        137
      ]
    }
  }
}
```